# using two layouts in a listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, baseadapter

i need to use two different layouts in a listview. The first position should use `R.layout.profile_element_one` while the rest use `R.layout.profile_element_two`. I am trying to set the text value of a textview in `R.layout.profile_element_one` but keep getting null pointer error. what am i doing wrong?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder1=null;
    View row = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    if(row==null)
    {

        if(getItemViewType(position)==0)
        {
            holder1 = new ViewHolder();
            row= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.profile_element_one, parent, false);
            holder1.Name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_profile_firstnameLastname);


        }
        else
        {
            row= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.profile_element_two, parent, false);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        if(position ==1)
        {
            holder1 = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
     }



    if(position ==1)
    {
        holder1.Name.setText(  this.obj.getFirst_name() +this.obj.getLast_name());

    }




    return row;
}



static  public class ViewHolder {
    TextView Name;

}





            @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    int type;
    if (position== 0)
    {
        type = 0;
    } 
    else
    {
        type =1;
    }
    return type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `getViewTypeCount` and `getItemViewType` method in order to say to your adapter that you need different layouts for your listview rows :

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2; // meaning that you have two kind of row
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (condition) ? 0 : 1; // condition : is a condition to know each row is being created
}
```

**BE CAREFUL** : The returned integer in the previous method is zero-based numbering !!!

Comment: What do you mean by didn't help ? Did you get errors ?? May be you did it wrong !!! be precise !

Answer (score 0):

just remove the null check and it would work:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder1=null;
    View row = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        if(position==0)
        {
            holder1 = new ViewHolder();
            row= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.profile_element_one, parent, false);
            holder1.Name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_profile_firstnameLastname);


        }
        else
        {
            row= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.profile_element_two, parent, false);
        }


        if(position ==0)
        {
            holder1 = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

        holder1.Name.setText(  this.obj.getFirst_name() +this.obj.getLast_name());

    }




    return row;
}
```